# How to Find the Explicit Formulation of a Transcendental Equation Root when Sympy Returns the LambertW Function?

Tags: python, sympy

I need to solve a transcendental equation that has four solutions using Sympy, but one of these solutions does not appear explicitly and is given in terms of LambertW function.

I would like to be able to write this solution in an explicit form. How can I achieve this?

My code:

```
# Modules
import sympy

# Parameters: real and positive values
beta = sympy.Symbol('beta', positive = True, real = True)
epsilon = sympy.Symbol('epsilon', positive = True, real = True)
delta = sympy.Symbol('delta', positive = True, real = True)
sigma = sympy.Symbol('sigma', positive = True, real = True)
gamma = sympy.Symbol('gamma', positive = True, real = True)
mu = sympy.Symbol('mu', positive = True, real = True)
psi = sympy.Symbol('psi', positive = True, real = True)
N = sympy.Symbol('N', positive = True, real = True)
B = sympy.Symbol('B', positive = True, real = True)
L = sympy.Symbol('L', positive = True, real = True)
tau = sympy.Symbol('tau', positive = True, real = True)


# Variables: all are real values and >= 0
S = sympy.Symbol('S', negative = False, real = True)
V = sympy.Symbol('V', negative = False, real = True)
I = sympy.Symbol('I', negative = False, real = True)
R = sympy.Symbol('R', negative = False, real = True)


# Equilibria
# Dictionary :: output order to variables :: I, R, S, V
sol1, sol2, sol3 = sympy.solve([B + epsilon*V + delta*R - psi*S - mu*S - beta*S*I/N, psi*S - epsilon*V - mu*V - sigma*beta*V*I/N, beta*S*I/N + sigma*beta*V*I/N - mu*I - gamma*I, gamma*I - mu*R - delta*R], S, V, I, R, dict=True)

# Equilibria point trivial (sol1)::
sol_trivial = list(sol1.values())
It, Rt, St, Vt = sol_trivial

# Linear Part
k = beta*St/N + sigma*beta*Vt/N - (mu + gamma)

A = sympy.Matrix([[-mu, epsilon, beta*St/N, delta], [0, -epsilon-mu, -sigma*beta*Vt/N, 0], [0, 0, k, 0], [0, 0, gamma, -mu-delta]])
B = sympy.Matrix([[-sigma, 0, 0, 0], [sigma, 0, 0, 0], [0, 0, 0, 0], [0, 0, 0, 0]])
Id = sympy.Matrix([[1, 0, 0, 0], [0, 1, 0, 0], [0, 0, 1, 0], [0, 0, 0, 1]])
Delta = (A + L*Id + B*sympy.exp(-L*tau))
det_Delta = Delta.det()

# Eigenvalues (are the solutions (L variable) to characterist equation "det_Delta")
auto1, auto2, auto3, auto4 = sympy.solve(det_Delta, L)
```

The values `auto1`, `auto2`, `auto3`, and `auto4` are:

```
auto1 = mu
auto2 = (tau*(epsilon + mu) + LambertW(sigma*tau*exp(-tau*(epsilon + mu))))/tau
auto3 = (-B*beta*epsilon - B*beta*mu - B*beta*psi*sigma + N*epsilon*gamma*mu + N*epsilon*mu**2 + N*gamma*mu**2 + N*gamma*mu*psi + N*mu**3 + N*mu**2*psi)/(N*mu*(epsilon + mu + psi))
auto4 = delta + mu
```

The important information is that there are positive eigenvalues and, of course, this equilibria is unstable.

Now, notice that only `auto2` is not an explicit value because of the LambertW function. Is it possible "convert" this output to a closed-form solution to make this like the others? How can I do that?

Comment: `LambertW(x)` is about as explicit as getting a solution with `cos(x)`. What do you want to do with `auto2` that makes `W` undesireable?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Lambert W function is used precisely to give explicit solutions to transcendental equations whose solutions cannot otherwise be expressed using elementary functions. I don't see why you say that it is not "explicit".

Your solution is this:

```
In [1]: auto2 = S('(tau*(epsilon + mu) + LambertW(sigma*tau*exp(-tau*(epsilon + mu))))/tau')

In [2]: auto2
Out[2]: 
             ⎛     -τ⋅(ε + μ)⎞
τ⋅(ε + μ) + W⎝σ⋅τ⋅ℯ          ⎠
──────────────────────────────
              τ
```

Now there might be a way to simplify this to something that does not involve the `W` function. The critical identity is

```
In [5]: Eq(LambertW(x*exp(x)), x)
Out[5]: 
 ⎛   x⎞    
W⎝x⋅ℯ ⎠ = x
```

except that this only holds when `x >= -1`. If you can find a substitution that brings your solution into that form then maybe you can eliminate the W function. I don't see how to do that though for your equation in particular. A substitution can reduce it to `W(a*x*exp(x))` but then you still have to deal with the `a` somehow.

I don't know about your equations in particular because it looks like an extension on the basic SIR model but at least for the basic SIR model the solution cannot be expressed without the use of the Lambert W function:

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Compartmental_models_in_epidemiology#The_SIR_model_without_birth_and_death